# Unable to delete row in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Google App Engine and datastore so please be patient :)

My code below is trying to ask for user inputs, either entering or deleting an entry, and the results will be shown directly in a table on the same page. When I tried to delete a particular entry in the datastore, the row does not get deleted in the datastore and sometimes new rows with empty data are added. Why does this happen?

```
    class Events(ndb.Model):
        name = ndb.StringProperty()
        desc = ndb.StringProperty()

    class Promote(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            query = ndb.gql("SELECT * "
                            "FROM Events "
                            )
            template_values = {"events" : query,}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('promote.htm')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

        def post(self):
            event = Events(name = self.request.get('name'), desc = self.request.get('desc'))
            event.put()
            self.redirect('/promote')

    class Delete(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
            event = ndb.Key('Events', self.request.get('eventname'))
            event.delete()
            self.redirect('/promote')


    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Main),
                                   ('/publicsearch', PublicSearch),
                                   ('/promote', Promote),
                                   ('/delete',Delete)],
                                  debug=True)
```

This is the html code

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class = "container">
             <form action="/promote" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                  <p> Promote your event here! </p>
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                  <div class="span6">
                  <p> Name of event: <br>
                  <textarea class="input-block-level" name="name" rows="1" cols = "50"> </textarea></p>
                  <p> Event description: <br>
                  <textarea class="input-block-level" name="desc" rows="3" cols = "50"> </textarea></p>
                  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <h4> Events feed </h4>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="30%">Name</th>
                <th width="60%">Description</th>
                <th>Delete Event</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for event in events %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ event.name }} </td>
                <td>{{ event.desc }}  </td>
                <td>                    
                  <form action="/delete" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="eventkey" value="{{ event.key.urlsafe() }}">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                  </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is not based on the event name, because you haven't specified any key when creating the events: they'll just use a numeric id.

The better thing to do here would be to put the actual key in the hidden input: you can use the `urlsafe` method to output a string that can be used in templates.

```
<input type="hidden" name="eventkey" value="{{ event.key.urlsafe() }}">
```

and in the view:

```
event = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('eventkey'))
```

Comment: Hey thanks! After trying out your code, what happens now is that, on the first delete, a new row with empty data is still added and the original record remains. On the second delete, the original record is deleted but the empty row remains.

And how do you specify a key out of the fields in a record?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. There's nothing in my code that would create a new row. It sounds like you are somehow sometimes going to /promote instead of /delete. And you don't really want to create a key from the name field, unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Ok I understand your point on creating a key from the name field. About going to /promote instead of /delete I think you may be right. Because when I click 'delete' on the page while having new values in the 'name' and 'desc' fields of another form (which is on the same page), it ends up posting these values to the datastore. I have updated a fuller version of the html code on the main entry. Could it be a problem with the html code?